# Tkinter - Asking the user for integer input until they give a valid response in tkinter entry box

Tags: python, tkinter, user-input, messagebox, tkinter-entry

I am writing a program which takes users personal information like name age state etc

```
myfont = f.Font(family='Maiandra GD')
agel = Label(root, text="Age    :", font=myfont, bg="#C5B358",  bd=4, relief="raised").place(relx=0.4, rely=0.62, relwidth=0.08, anchor='n')
ageE = Entry(root, font=myfont, bd=2, relief="sunken").place(relx=0.54, rely=0.62, width=265, anchor='n')


button = Button(root, text="START", font=myfont, borderwidth=10, bg="#C5B358", command=start).place(relx=0.5, rely=0.735, relwidth=0.235, anchor='n')
```

But instead of accepting a string input for age,I want the program to popup an error message box asking for integer only input

This is what i have tried so far and it is not working

```
def start():
    print("START")


def popup():
    messagebox.showerror("Invalid input !!", "Insert only integers in age entry!")



v = StringVar()
agel = Label(root, text="Age    :", font=myfont, bg="#C5B358",  bd=4, relief="raised").place(relx=0.4, rely=0.62, relwidth=0.08, anchor='n')
ageE = Entry(root, font=myfont, bd=2, relief="sunken", textvariable=v).place(relx=0.54, rely=0.62, width=265, anchor='n')
s=v.get()


if s.isnumeric():
    button = Button(root, text="START", font=myfont, borderwidth=10, bg="#C5B358", command=start).place(relx=0.5, rely=0.735, relwidth=0.235, anchor='n')
else:
    button = Button(root, text="START", font=myfont, borderwidth=10, bg="#C5B358", command=popup).place(relx=0.5, rely=0.735, relwidth=0.235, anchor='n')
```

Comment: First you have to understand [Event-driven_programming](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming). Read through [`[tkinter] event driven programming`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+%5Btkinter%5D+event+driven+programming+entry)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try to convert a string that can't be converted to integer, interpreter will throw a value error.

```
try:
    input_age = int(ageE.get())
except ValueError:
    messagebox.showerror('"Invalid input !!", "Insert only integers in age entry!"')
```

Comment: Hey i tried that but its still not working the popup with this code appears as soon as the program is started

Comment: `button = Button(root, text="START", font=myfont, borderwidth=10, bg="#C5B358", command=lambda: start()).place(relx=0.5, rely=0.735, relwidth=0.235, anchor='n')`

you have to add lambda to the command arguement